# hudson ant netbeans custom configuration

Tags: ant, hudson

Hi i have the following build-impl.xml file.

```
<project name="MyProject-impl" default="build" basedir=".." xmlns:webproject3="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/3" xmlns:webproject2="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/2" xmlns:jaxws="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/jax-ws/1" xmlns:webproject1="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/1">
    <import file="ant-deploy.xml"/>
    <target name="default" depends="dist,javadoc" description="Build whole project."/>
</project>
```

The problem is that ant-deploy.xml is not checked in and I do not want it to be checked in. Instead i want to be able to reference ant-deploy.xml from another file. How can I do this.

example ant-deploy.xml is put in C:\antDeployScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The way i did it was

```
<property name="ant.deploy.folder" value="."/>
<import file="${ant.deploy.folder}/ant-deploy.xml"/>
```

Than in the advance setting of ant --> properties

```
ant.deploy.folder=/shared/ant/
```